# Merge lines falling between and not including a repeating pattern with sed

Tags: regex, awk, sed

I have a file with number of lines containing time stamps and few lines in between. For example,

```
TIMESTAMP MESSAGE
TRAIL 1
TRAIL 2
TIMESTAMP MESSAGE2
TRAIL 21
TRAIL 22 ...
```

I want to add all trail messages into a single line, or better yet all lines between two time stamps to get into a single line, so that my output would look something like

```
TIMESTAMP MESSAGE TRAIL 1 TRAIL 2
TIMESTAMP MESSAGE2 TRAIL 21 TRAIL 22 ...
```

I went through few questions here which are similar but none worked in my case. I tried using

```
sed -i '/pattern_for_timestamp/{n;:l N;/pattern_for_timestamp/b ; s/\n// ; bl}'
```

but it only changes every *alternative* occurrence of the pattern. There need not be any pattern in the trail messages. I would prefer using `sed` or `awk` in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would go with collecting the lines in hold-space until they are complete, and then modify and print, e.g.:

*parse.sed*

```sed
/^TIMESTAMP/ b prn            # Run the prn subroutine
H                             # Anything else is appended to hold-space
$ b prn                       # Also run prn at end-of-input
b                             # Process next line

:prn
x                             # Swap pattern-space and hold-space
s/\n/ /g                      # Replace \n with space
1!p                           # Print the result if not on the first line
```

Run it like this:

```
sed -nf parse.sed infile
```

Or as a one-liner:

```
sed -n '/^TIMESTAMP/bp;H;$bp;b;:p;x;s/\n/ /g;1!p' infile
```

Output:

```
TIMESTAMP MESSAGE TRAIL 1 TRAIL 2
TIMESTAMP MESSAGE2 TRAIL 21 TRAIL 22 ...
```

Comment: This works just as expected, and I somehow prefer sed over awk/gawk and hence accepted.

Answer (score 3):

With gawk you can use a regex as your record separator and then use the (gawk-only) built-in `RT` to recover its value on output:

```
$ cat file
20170102 MESSAGE
TRAIL 1
TRAIL 2
20170312 MESSAGE2
TRAIL 21
TRAIL 22
20170527 MESSAGE3
TRAIL 31
TRAIL 32

$ gawk -v RS="[0-9]{8}" 'NR>1{gsub("\n", " "); print ts $0} {ts=RT}' file
20170102 MESSAGE TRAIL 1 TRAIL 2 
20170312 MESSAGE2 TRAIL 21 TRAIL 22 
20170527 MESSAGE3 TRAIL 31 TRAIL 32
```

Comment: this looks more like what OP wanted... `/pattern_for_timestamp/`

Answer (score 1):

Here is my try in awk:

```
awk '/^TIMESTAMP/{ if (NR > 1){ ORS = ""; print "\n"} ORS = " " };1' file
```

Output:

```
TIMESTAMP MESSAGE TRAIL 1 TRAIL 2
TIMESTAMP MESSAGE2 TRAIL 21 TRAIL 22
```

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed ':a;N;/\nTIMESTAMP/!s/\n/ /;ta;P;D' file
```

Gather up lines in the patten space replacing newlines by spaces then print the first line on encountering the next `TIMESTAMP`.

N.B. Expect that the first line is `TIMESTAMP`, if not use:

```
sed '/^TIMESTAMP/!b;:a;N;/\nTIMESTAMP/!s/\n/ /;ta;P;D' file
```